# Python Matplolib - Multiple radar plot with axis scale variation

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

How can this two approaches be merged into the same program?

On one hand, there's [this code](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/radar_chart.html) from matplotlib for creating radar charts.

On the other hand, [this code](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6084/how-do-i-create-a-complex-radar-chart) lets you to change the scale of each axis and even add negative numbers to it.

The merger I'm looking for is to be able to plot lots of different data in the same way as in the matplotlib approach, but being able to change in each one of those plots, the axis scale.

EDIT: code attempted

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import seaborn as sns # improves plot aesthetics


def _invert(x, limits):
    """inverts a value x on a scale from
    limits[0] to limits[1]"""
    return limits[1] - (x - limits[0])

def _scale_data(data, ranges):
    """scales data[1:] to ranges[0],
    inverts if the scale is reversed"""
    # for d, (y1, y2) in zip(data[1:], ranges[1:]):
    for d, (y1, y2) in zip(data, ranges):
        assert (y1 <= d <= y2) or (y2 <= d <= y1)

    x1, x2 = ranges[0]
    d = data[0]

    if x1 > x2:
        d = _invert(d, (x1, x2))
        x1, x2 = x2, x1

    sdata = [d]

    for d, (y1, y2) in zip(data[1:], ranges[1:]):
        if y1 > y2:
            d = _invert(d, (y1, y2))
            y1, y2 = y2, y1

        sdata.append((d-y1) / (y2-y1) * (x2 - x1) + x1)

    return sdata

def set_rgrids(self, radii, labels=None, angle=None, fmt=None,
               **kwargs):
    """
    Set the radial locations and labels of the *r* grids.
    The labels will appear at radial distances *radii* at the
    given *angle* in degrees.
    *labels*, if not None, is a ``len(radii)`` list of strings of the
    labels to use at each radius.
    If *labels* is None, the built-in formatter will be used.
    Return value is a list of tuples (*line*, *label*), where
    *line* is :class:`~matplotlib.lines.Line2D` instances and the
    *label* is :class:`~matplotlib.text.Text` instances.
    kwargs are optional text properties for the labels:
    %(Text)s
    ACCEPTS: sequence of floats
    """
    # Make sure we take into account unitized data
    radii = self.convert_xunits(radii)
    radii = np.asarray(radii)
    rmin = radii.min()
    # if rmin <= 0:
    #     raise ValueError('radial grids must be strictly positive')

    self.set_yticks(radii)
    if labels is not None:
        self.set_yticklabels(labels)
    elif fmt is not None:
        self.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter(fmt))
    if angle is None:
        angle = self.get_rlabel_position()
    self.set_rlabel_position(angle)
    for t in self.yaxis.get_ticklabels():
        t.update(kwargs)
    return self.yaxis.get_gridlines(), self.yaxis.get_ticklabels()

class ComplexRadar():
    def __init__(self, fig, variables, ranges,
                 n_ordinate_levels=6):
        angles = np.arange(0, 360, 360./len(variables))

        axes = [fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9],polar=True,
                label = "axes{}".format(i)) 
                for i in range(len(variables))]
        l, text = axes[0].set_thetagrids(angles, 
                                         labels=variables)
        [txt.set_rotation(angle-90) for txt, angle 
             in zip(text, angles)]
        for ax in axes[1:]:
            ax.patch.set_visible(False)
            ax.grid("off")
            ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
        for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
            grid = np.linspace(*ranges[i], 
                               num=n_ordinate_levels)
            gridlabel = ["{}".format(round(x,2)) 
                         for x in grid]
            if ranges[i][0] > ranges[i][1]:
                grid = grid[::-1] # hack to invert grid
                          # gridlabels aren't reversed
            gridlabel[0] = "" # clean up origin
            # ax.set_rgrids(grid, labels=gridlabel, angle=angles[i])
            set_rgrids(ax, grid, labels=gridlabel, angle=angles[i])
            #ax.spines["polar"].set_visible(False)
            ax.set_ylim(*ranges[i])
        # variables for plotting
        self.angle = np.deg2rad(np.r_[angles, angles[0]])
        self.ranges = ranges
        self.ax = axes[0]
    def plot(self, data, *args, **kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        self.ax.plot(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)
    def fill(self, data, *args, **kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        self.ax.fill(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)

# example data
variables = ('ST-1', 'ST-2', 'ST-3', 'ST-4', 'ST-5', 'ST-6', 'ST-7', 'ST-16', 'SC-1', 'SC-2')
data = (34.0, 32.1, 28.6, 28.6, 28.9, 28.3, 26.3, 39.6, 3.2, 1.3)
ranges = [(20, 40), (20, 40),(20, 40),(20, 40),(20, 40),(20, 40),(20, 40),(20, 40),(0, 5), (0, 5)]            


# plotting
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))
radar = ComplexRadar(fig1, variables, ranges)
radar.plot(data, label='Test 1')
radar.fill(data, alpha=0.2)

data = (20.0, 23.4, 22.7, 21.3, 26.9, 26.2, 21.3, 22.3, 3.7, 1.0)
radar = ComplexRadar(fig1, variables, ranges)
radar.plot(data, label='Test 2')
radar.fill(data, alpha=0.2)

data = (38.0, 30.1, 25.6, 22.6, 29.9, 38.3, 28.3, 24.6, 3.0, 1.8)
radar = ComplexRadar(fig1, variables, ranges)
radar.plot(data, label='Test 3')
radar.fill(data, alpha=0.2)

labels = ('Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3')
legend = radar.legend(labels, loc=(0.9, .95), labelspacing=0.1, fontsize='small')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you put your code into the question?

Comment: You've got a pretty good starting point with the two links you've provided. What have been your attempts to merge them?

Comment: @DavidG I'm stuck here. I'm not even able to make the legends appear